# Objective C How to call a method in view controller from sub view

Tags: objective-c

Newbee question here -

I have this method in the view controller m:

```
-(void) backToHP:(id<SwitchViewProtocol>) fromView{

    [(UIView *)self.currentView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.currentView clearView];
    [self.view addSubview:_hpView];
    self.currentView = nil;

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:0.2];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

    [[self.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
}
```

I try to invoke it from a subclass. 
subclass h:

```
@interface SetNotificationClass : UIView < SwitchViewProtocol> {

    habitsViewController *hvc;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) habitsViewController *hvc;
```

subclass m:

```
@synthesize hvc;

- (IBAction)saveNotificationClick:(id)sender {
   // [self scheduleAlarm];
    [hvc backToHP:nil];
}
```

I get the "method not found" error. any idea?

Thanks

Comment: You should use delegation and set your hvc as the delegate of it's subview.

Comment: What's `habitsViewController`? We need to see the rest of your code. (also, is the `method not found` a compile-time or run-time error?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you initialize hvc? You're not sending backToHP: to nil, right? I'd also probably just set the view controller as the delegate of the view, rather than creating a new property.